# Want to update AspNetUser table ,Identity 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want to update AspNetUser's all fields through EntityFramework,and code is given

```
 public CustomJsonResult SaveUser(UserEditFormModel userRecord)
 {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid) CustomJson(userRecord);
       var user = Mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(userRecord);
       return CustomJson(userRecord);
 }
```

> //----error: userRecord is not mapped with ApplecationUser

Comment: Don't use `asp.net identity` with entity framework. Use the models built with default app template

Comment: sorry but i have to use this .

Comment: At least use ADO.NET `SqlCommand`